# Meaning of the word Agency in scientific papers

Tags: meaning

What is the definition of the word agency, used in this context:

A starship captain on the inside cannot steer the bubble or turn it on or off; some external agency must set it up ahead of time
(https://www.bibliotecapleyades.net/ciencia/negativeenergy/negativeenergy.htm)

I have seen this use of the word agency in several scientific papers. It has nothing to do with agencies, offices, organizations. But my dictionary does not provode the correct definition.

EDiT: thanks to the contributors that cared about the question.

Comment: Starships in scientific papers? References?

Comment: Check the link I provided. It cites papers and scientists. Your remark sounds more like a sarcasm than a real interest in the question

Comment: @winston - see Merriam-Websters's third sense - instrumentality - at http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agency. I think this borders on business/academic jargon, but M-W lists this sense without restriction.

Answer (score 4):

> **agency** **2.** ... a thing or person that acts to produce a particular result.
> "the movies could be an agency molding the values of the public" [freedictionary (Oxford Languages)](https://www.google.com/search?q=free%20dictionary&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS911US911&oq=free&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i59l2j0i67j69i60j69i61l2.1320j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#dobs=agency)

Comment: This use of *ageny* borders on both *agent* and *actor* alike -- and for good reason unrelated to guild membership cards. :)